# Why is it not possible to access objects that seem to be in scope when pausing execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart

I'm learning Dart and Flutter, and I'm finding it a mostly pleasureable experience. I'm making an app that I want to communicate with Amazon AWS resources. However, I'm stuck with an issue that I haven't been able to resolve for a while now.

I'm making a function for getting keys and tokens necessary for making authenticated requests to the API at AWS. I'm using a library function from AWS Amplify to get an AuthSession object. If I set a breakpoint to just after the AuthSession object has been retrieved, it seems as if this object contains some object called AuthSession.credentials. This in turn contains awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey and sessionToken, which are the tokens and keys that I need. I can access them in the debug console when execution is paused.

```
Future<AWSCredentials> getAWSCredentials() async {
  final AuthSession authSession = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));
  final a = 1; // I set a breakpoint on this line
  //final AWSCredentials awsCredentials = authSession.credentials;
  //return awsCredentials;
}
```

[VS Code screenshot of objects in scope at breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVTyA.png)

However, if I try to make the function return this AuthSession (by uncommenting the last two lines of the above function), or one of the tokens directly, it doesn't compile anymore and I get the error message

> The getter 'credentials' isn't defined for the type 'AuthSession'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'credentials', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'credentials'. dart(undefined_getter)

I tried to dig into the code defining the class AuthSession, and it doesn't seem to contain any reference to the credentials object. However, it's obviously there at runtime. Why can't I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `AuthSession` does not contain any member called `credentials`, so when casting the result of `fetchAuthSession()` to an `AuthSession`, it is not possible to access that member. However, the subclass `CognitoAuthSession` does contain the `credentials` member, so casting the result to that type allows access to `authSession.credentials`.

So the call to `fetchAuthSession()` should be

```
final CognitoAuthSession authSession = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
        options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));
```

Comment: However, what I haven't figured out is how `fetchAuthSession` can return a `CognitoAuthSession` instead of an `AuthSession` - when I right-click the function in VS Code and click _Go to Definition_, it looks like this:
`Future<AuthSession> fetchAuthSession({AuthSessionOptions options}) { [...] }`

I figured out that I had to cast to `CognitoAuthSession` by a comment from user horgag in this [Github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/105)